# Cannot reach Controller/Action on LogOff button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have used the MVC template in an application and modified it as I need. On Logout button click, I should be able to reach the logout action where I define my logout logic. But when I click the button, it directly takes me to the login screen without hitting the logoff action in the controller.

I tried adding an action link and specifying explicitly to reach the logoff action and it did not work either. 
If I remove this action, it throws an error that it's not found. I checked in the fiddler tool and this action is called on the button click and redirected to Login, but the breakpoint is never hit or if I change the content inside the logoff action, it is not reflected.
I also tried using a different name for the same action, no change in the behavior was found.

Here is the view and controller action.

```
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

The partial view embedded in layout:

```
    @if (1==1)
    {
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  

    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <p class="navbar-text">Allturna's Insights Portal</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-text">Hello!</p> @*Use username here from viewdata*@
                </li>
                <li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Tenants", "GetTenant", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, null)
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                <li><img src="~/Content/Image/Allturna_logo.png" height="50" width="220" /></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
}
```

}

The RouteConfig.cs is as below:

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I have not been able to figure out why the logoff button click/form submission can not reach the logoff action. I would appreciate any help.

As I am working on it, I wanted to add some additional notes. If I use the default aspnet template with identity, it reaches the logoff button. But I am trying to implement my own login and logout logic without using Identity. That's when it does not hit the logoff.

I have posted both logic (with/without identity) hits the logoff as expected.

The following with Identity works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                //Add tenantId to session from user info (temporary testing with Allturna)
                Session["TenantId"] = 1;
                Session["AccessToken"] = "my token";
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

when I use the following login logic (without identity), the Logoff does not get hit.

```
            [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        //get the authentication URL
        string strJwtToken = string.Empty;
        string strAuthenticationUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AuthenticationServerEndPoint");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strAuthenticationUrl))
            throw new Exception("Authentication Endpoint is not specified.");

        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(strAuthenticationUrl, "Authenticate");
        dynamic objAuthentication = new ExpandoObject();
        objAuthentication.UserName = model.Email;
        objAuthentication.Password = model.Password;
        client.AddJsonBody(objAuthentication);
        HttpStatusCode httpReturnCode = client.Post(out strJwtToken);

        if (httpReturnCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Session["AccessToken"] = strJwtToken;

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

I would need to understand what does the identity framework/SignInManager does that my logic is missing and how I can add that to my logic and make the logout work correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using calling logoff with a parameter from your post : using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))  but your logoog action does not accepts any param , change public ActionResult LogOff() to public ActionResult LogOff(string id) and it should work

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Thanks. But I am using the following overload of beginform where it's the html attribute, not a parameter. public static System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm BeginForm (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes);

Comment: Using the code you have posted, it works for me.  Have you put a breakpoint on the "return" in you LogOff method? Does it hit it?  If not, have you looked in dev tools on the browser (F12)? On the network tab, does anything come back red?

Comment: @BattlFrog I have added breakpoints in every line, but it doesn't hit anywhere and directly returns the login page by going to Login action. There is nothing in red in the network tab either.

Comment: Can you post the RouteConfig.cs file?

Comment: @BattlFrog I have added the RouteConfig.cs to my post above.

Comment: Well that seems fine.  Any errors in the F12 console?

Comment: @BattlFrog I did not not find any errors in F12 console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194836/discussion-between-battlfrog-and-meenakshi-dash).